# on master branch -- told to "specify a branch"

Tags: default, git-remote

We use a custom script to build and publish documentation from Flare. I have been using the same steps for 2 months and suddenly something has changed and the script no longer executes properly. Currently it gives me this message: "You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."
I am on branch "Master" and I don't ever run this command from any other branch. Why is it telling me this?

I work in a collaborative setting so there are 3 of us pushing and pulling to/from a main repository in GitHub. We use "fork and branch workflow". I sync my local repo, checkout a branch, and do my work on the branch. Then I add, commit and push my work, I then merge it in GitHub. My PowerShell script is then on the 'master' branch. Then I run this custom script to publish my work. This is when I get the message.

Why do I get this message at this point and not when I type the command 'git pull upstream master'? THAT command executes fine.

I always progress through the same set of steps in the same order, but something is suddenly amiss. My coworkers do the same thing and they have no issues. One of them is now completing my publishing for me because we don't know the issue.
**Any ideas of what to check? **
Everything says "up-to-date" and "nothing to add' and the like.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).